# ReduxForm select value option is removed by filter, but option remains selected

Tags: select, filter, react-redux, redux-form

I'm using Redux-form and I have a normal  dropdown

there are 3 options in the list.
option 1
option 2
option 3
I select option 3.
I then go into my filter input field and type 1.
Now the list just contains option 1.
but option 3 is still selected in the form state.

How do I get the form to update and realize that that option isn't in the list anymore and go to default?

There's a couple ways I've though about doing it but not sure what's best.

I could write some state change logic in formReducer.plugin with an /CHANGE action type and filter field.

I could perhaps call onChange event on the select whenever I type in filter field.

I could always check in the select component render function if the current states selected value is in the list and if not, call a redux-form change action on the select to undefined.

r something better???

Comment: Add some sample code.  I'll provide a guess answer, but w/o code, it's really just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some component for your select, then you need to override the `onChange` prop to make sure your component gets the onChange event as well as the `redux-form` field `input`.

```
export const renderSelect = ({input, meta: { touched, error }, ...rest}) => {
    return <Form.Select  {...input} {...rest}
         onChange={ (event, data) => { input.onChange(data.value);}}
    />
};

const MyFormComponent = (props) => {
  const {brandData, productData, groupData} = props.optionsData;
  return (
    <Form>
      <Field name='brandData' options={brandData} component={renderSelect}/>
      <Field name='productData' options={productData} component={renderSelect}/>
      <Field name='groupData' options={groupData} component={renderSelect}/>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

You can see a similar thing done in the `redux-form` example for integrating with 3rd party form components in their [`material-ui` example](https://redux-form.com/7.2.1/examples/material-ui/).